# Duplicate content in pdf created using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to convert html to pdf. In some cases, where html has svg charts, some of the data is duplicated in the generated pdf.

e.g. If the charts have legends, they are getting duplicated. See the screenshot below. City names and the percentages are repeated.

[image]

Below is the code to create pdf.

```
pdf.addHTML($("#page1"), options, function(){
            pdf.addPage();
            pdf.addHTML($("#page2"), options, function(){
                pdf.addPage();
                pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
            });
        });
```

**EDIT 1:**

This is what I have figured so far.

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="pieChart"></div>
</div>
```

When I do this, `pdf.addHTML($("#pieChart")`, no issues here.

But, when I do this, `pdf.addHTML($("#outerDiv")`, then labels get repeated.

and this is how I generate my c3js charts

```
var pieChart  = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#pieChart',
```

**EDIT 2:-**

Below is my entire code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gabelerner.github.io/canvg/rgbcolor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gabelerner.github.io/canvg/StackBlur.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gabelerner.github.io/canvg/canvg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-alpha1/html2canvas.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function replaceAllSVGsWithTempCanvas(elemSelector) {
        var svgElements = $(elemSelector).find('svg');

        //replace all svgs with a temp canvas
        svgElements.each(function() {
            var canvas, xml;

            // canvg doesn't cope very well with em font sizes so find the calculated size in pixels and replace it in the element.
            $.each($(this).find('[style*=em]'), function(index, el) {
                $(this).css('font-size', getStyle(el, 'font-size'));
            });

            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.className = "screenShotTempCanvas";

            //convert SVG into a XML string
            xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(this);

            // Removing the name space as IE throws an error
            xml = xml.replace(/xmlns=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg\"/, '');

            //draw the SVG onto a canvas
            canvg(canvas, xml);
            $(canvas).insertAfter(this);

            //hide the SVG element
            $(this).attr('class', 'tempHide');
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        genChart();
    });

    function genPDF() {
        var options = {
            background: '#fff'
        };
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

        replaceAllSVGsWithTempCanvas(".content");

        pdf.addHTML($("#chartOuter"), options, function() {
            pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');

            $(".content").find('.screenShotTempCanvas').remove();
            $(".content").find('.tempHide').show().removeClass('tempHide');

        });
    }

    function genChart() {
        var chart = c3.generate({
            data: {
                columns: [
                    ['data1', 30],
                    ['data2', 120],
                ],
                type: 'pie'
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body class="content">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                <div id="chartOuter">
                    <div id="chart"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <input type="button" onclick="genPDF();" value="Generate PDF" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT 3:-**

I tried just converting html to canvas using html2canvas. It is also giving the same issue.

**Edit 4:**

I could fix the duplicate issue now. But the charts and the text written to pdf are little bit blurry. Basically, I added function replaceAllSVGsWithTempCanvas and then use that while writing to pdf. But it seems this function does smething to the html that makes content written to pdf blurry. In fact pie charts etc, are no more circles but looks like oval shape.

Edited the question with modified js.

Comment: can you please upload your html,JS code to fiddle

Comment: @Raki I have edited the question and added the all the html and js code.

Comment: Jus add $(".c3 svg").css({"font-size":"0px"}); before pdf.addHTML(... As my anwer explains. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is a bug in html2canvas. You should add the bottom code after html2canvas is loaded to fix that (Credits goes to [this guy](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/541)):

```
NodeParser.prototype.getChildren = function(parentContainer) {
    return flatten([].filter.call(parentContainer.node.childNodes, renderableNode).map(function(node) {
        var container = [node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && node.parentElement.tagName !== "text" ? new TextContainer(node, parentContainer) : new NodeContainer(node, parentContainer)].filter(nonIgnoredElement);
        return node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && container.length && node.tagName !== "TEXTAREA" ? (container[0].isElementVisible() ? container.concat(this.getChildren(container[0])) : []) : container;
    }, this));
};
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0LhL5x2/)

Since html2canvas loads as a module, you should directly find `NodeParser.prototype.getChildren` in the source code and edit it to match above. That means you can't load it from CDN.

Comment: In which file should I change? addhtml.js ? or jspdf.debug.js?

Comment: @anything Umm, html2canvas.js.

Comment: It fixed the issue for pie charts but the issue still remains for the bar charts line charts. The labels on x and y axis gets repeated. Any ideas?

Comment: Noticed you were not using the latest version of html2canvas. Also, didn't you notice it wasn't working on Firefox, and it is working poorly in IE before posting your question? It never worked to begin with.

Comment: I was not aware of this.

Comment: Are there any other alternatives then?

Comment: I always used html2canvas when I needed to render html. Just not with svg. I will look into it in detail later. Until then I am not sure if there are any alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I think made it work correctly in two steps.
**First,** I commented out the "addhtml plugin" because I had this error in my console:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/plugins/addhtml.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

**Second,** I changed the pdf source from `#chartOuter` to `#chart`.

```
    pdf.addHTML($("#chart"), options, function () {
    var string = pdf.output('datauristring');
    $('.preview-pane').attr('src', string)
});
```

And there is no more dedoubling.

**-----

EDIT** *(since I misunderstood the question at first)*

It is needed to use the outer div... And maybe the full page.

Okay... To be honest, I don't know why this text issue happens.
But I noticed that the duplicate text has serif even if it is specified "sans-serif".
So I focused on this.
I tried to change the font-size... It affected the duplicate, but the text didn't follow the css rule. Okay.

Then I tried to just remove the text before the pdf creation part... And magic!
;)

```
$(".c3 svg").css({"font-size":"0px"});
```

Here is the complete script, I didn't touch the rest of your original code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        genChart();
    });

    function genPDF() {
        var options = { background: '#fff'};
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

        $(".c3 svg").css({"font-size":"0px"});    // <-- This does the trick !

        pdf.addHTML($("#chartOuter"), options, function () {
            var string = pdf.output('datauristring');
            $('.preview-pane').attr('src', string)
        });
    }

    function genChart() {
        var chart = c3.generate({
            data: {
                columns: [
                    ['data1', 30],
                    ['data2', 120],
                ],
                type : 'pie'
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please see my comments in first edit. It works when I use #chart but now when I use #chartOuter.

Comment: Ok... But why do you need to use the outer div then ?

Comment: See there are lots of other stuff in the html that I need to write in pdf. I can very well just select the chart div and write to pdf but then all the other css and html will have to be done manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using ChartJS instead of C3.

I've adapted your code and tried it with success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-alpha1/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/plugins/addhtml.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            genChart();
        });

        function genPDF() {
            var options = { background: '#fff'};
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

            pdf.addHTML($("#chartOuter"), options, function () {
                var string = pdf.output('datauristring');
                $('.preview-pane').attr('src', string)
            });
        }

        function genChart () {
          var ctx = $("#chart");
          var options = {};

          var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'pie',
              data: {
                    labels: [
                        "data1",
                        "data2"
                    ],
                    datasets: [{
                            data: [30, 120],
                            backgroundColor: [
                                "#FF6384",
                                "#36A2EB"
                            ],
                            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                                "#FF6384",
                                "#36A2EB"
                            ]
                        }]
                },
              options: options
          });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                <div id="chartOuter">
                    <!-- <div id="chart"></div> -->
                    <canvas id="chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <iframe height="550px" class="preview-pane" type="application/pdf" width="100%" frameborder="0" style="position:relative;z-index:999"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <input type="button" onclick="genPDF();" value="Generate PDF"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can not change the chart library right now as we have created so many charts already and we will have to rewrite everything. Which is not feasible at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically loading pdf blurry, the same file official demo is very clear. I can't locate the problem?

Use the chrome browser. Version 73.0.3683.86 (official version) (64-bit)
Here is my code：

```js
  async process(buffer, index) {
      
      // Processing the decrypted data stream
      let uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
      var word = await this.Uint8ToBase64(uint8Array);
      var decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(word, this.authorKey, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
      });
      
      // Then turn wordArray to uint8Array
      let getUint8Array = await this.wordArrayToU8(decryptedData);
      
      // decryption ends
      this.loadingPdf(getUint8Array, index);
    },
    async loadingPdf(getUint8Array, index) {
      
      // render canvas
      let pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: getUint8Array, cMapUrl: cMapUrl, cMapPacked: cMapPacked  });
      let page = await pdf.getPage(1).then(page => {
        return page;
      });
      let canvas = document.getElementById("the-canvas" + index);
      const CSS_UNITS = 96.0 / 72.0;
      const DEFAULT_SCALE = 1.7;
      const UNKNOWN_SCALE = 0;
      let viewport = page.getViewport( DEFAULT_SCALE * CSS_UNITS);
      if (canvas.dataset.runed) return;

      canvas.width = viewport.width*CSS_UNITS;
      canvas.height = viewport.height*CSS_UNITS;
      this.canvasW =
        this.canvasW > (1000 / viewport.height) * viewport.width
          ? this.canvasW
          : (1000 / viewport.height) * viewport.width;
      canvas.style.width = (1000 / viewport.height) * viewport.width;
      canvas.dataset.runed = true;
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      
       // [Important] Turn off anti-aliasing
      context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
      context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
      context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
      context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
      await page.render({
        //enableWebGL: true,
        // canvasContext: context,
        transform: [CSS_UNITS, 0, 0, CSS_UNITS, 0, 0],
      //  transform: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        canvasContext: canvas.getContext("2d"),
        viewport: viewport
      });
      this.loadedPages.push(index)
    },
```

Comment: Please transform the Chinese comments into English ones.